# Add New record in the next row to the existing excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to add some data in existing Excel file from C# application. I have written a code from where I can create a new Excel file and I can add data one time. Now I want to append same Excel file for next records with existing code. But it keeps my record in the next column instead of next row in the Excel file.

```cs
// With the help of my code I get 2 values in the "colValuesInList"

var colValuesInList = (
   from DataRow dtRow in Resource.ReportDataTable.Rows 
   where Convert.ToString(dtRow["TestGenericName"]).ToLower()
             .Contains("petname01")|| 
             Convert.ToString(dtRow["TestGenericName"]).ToLower()
             . Contains("activityid")
   select Convert.ToString (dtRow ["Value"])).ToList();

   colValuesInList.ForEach((item) => carMakeDetails.Columns.Add(item));

// I already have created a Datatable with name "carMakeDetails" and already methods
// to create directoryPath and CreateExcelOfDataTable and save at a particular Location
// given below

string directoryPath =CreateDirectory();
string _excelResultLocation =CreateExcelOfDataTable(carMakeDetails, $@" 
{directoryPath}\\","CarDetails_ActivityIDSheet.xlsx");
```

I expect the output like

```
-------------------------------------------
HONDA       74753670  
BMW         74753724
----------------------------------------------
```

But the actual output is

```
-------------------------------------------------
HONDA       74753670    BMW         74753724
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why are you using `Columns.Add` wouldn't it be `Rows.Add`

Comment: I am getting error "{"Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"} " while using Rows.Add